# Is the loopback (127.0.0.1) a hardware setting?

Tags: ipv4, loopback-address

I've looked through posts with no real answer to this question: is the address `127.0.0.1` a hardware set address much like `promiscuous mode` is a hardware setting on devices? I've tried to set my address to `127.0.0.1` on `eth0`, disable the `lo`, and even change the `lo` address, to make packets go out the `eth0` port with address `127.0.0.1`. The packets always end up on the `lo` port when I use sniffing tools like wireshark. Is there a way to do this, is this hardware or hardcoded into the drivers?

Comment: According to this: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) they (127.0.01)  get dropped on any 'external' interface. What are you trying to do? You can use other 'local' reserved addresses such as '192.168...' to communicate on your local network.

Comment: Your wiki link states the "ipv4 standard" limits this range for loop back, but doesn't state how with is specifically implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loopback address is controlled by software (e.g. in the kernel). It is never associated with any hardware.

You don't specify your operating system, but unless it's very unusual, there really isn't a way to do what you ask (have packets addressed to 127.0.0.1 appear on an external interface).

**Update:**

Here's the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330):

> 127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host
> loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an
> address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host.
> This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback,
> but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network
> anywhere [RFC1700, page 5].

Comment: That's what I want to know, why is that?

Comment: ok, why wasn't the correct question, I mean how is this done?

Comment: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/drivers/net/loopback.c

Comment: I don't see in there where it limits of available IP addresses range for use only as loopback exclusively. (i.e. 127.0.0.0/8) It still leaves me the same question, is that set in software or hardware?